# How to get the diff of a single file with libgit2?

Tags: c, libgit2

Is there a function equivalent to `git diff FILE` in `libgit2`? In other words, how to efficiently retrieve the diff of a **single** file without having `libgit2` to look at other files in the working directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git diff FILE` will display the changes you've made relative to the index.

This can be achieved through the use of the libgit2 `git_diff_index_to_workdir()` function.

This function accepts a `git_diff_options` structure as a parameter into which you can provide a pathspec, or a list of pathspecs, you're specifically interested in.

**More information about this:**

- **[Documentation](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/bc2020d64869aa19a88b71aee33a24b54c178dab/include/git2/diff.h#L543-L563)** of this function.
- **[Unit test](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/bc2020d64869aa19a88b71aee33a24b54c178dab/tests-clar/diff/workdir.c#L203-L308)** leveraging this use case.