# git diff of just one file

Tags: c, libgit2

The only way I found to get a diff from a single file using **libgit2** is through **git_diff_foreach** and checking the filename at the **diff_file_cb** callback.

It's not the way I wanted to do this, I was looking for something easier.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: [Have you looked at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563021/how-to-get-the-diff-of-a-single-file-with-libgit2)

Comment: Yes I have. I think the way to solve it is using git_diff_index_to_workdir() with the pathspec option

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify, `git_diff_index_to_workdir` (or `git_diff_tree_to_tree` or another such function) finds the list of changed files and then `git_diff_foreach` walks through the found files and the text of the diffs.  You can pass a "pathspec" in the options structure for `git_diff_index_to_workdir` that will limit the files being checked. You would do that as mentioned in the prior answer.

As a slightly broader example, if you wanted to diff a more complex set of files, you could write something like:

```
git_diff *diff;
git_diff_options opts = GIT_DIFF_OPTIONS_INIT;
char *files[3];

files[0] = "myfile.txt";
files[1] = "yourfile.txt";
files[2] = "some/directory/*.h"

opts.pathspec.count = 3;
opts.pathspec.strings = files;

if (git_diff_index_to_workdir(&diff, repo, NULL, &opts) < 0) {
    printf("Failed to diff\n");
    exit(1);
}

git_diff_foreach(diff, file_cb, NULL, NULL, NULL);

git_diff_free(diff);
```

You can pass as many file names or file patterns as you like.  If you want to disable the pattern matching behavior (i.e. expanding `*` and such), you can write `opts.flags |= GIT_DIFF_DISABLE_PATHSPEC_MATCH` and only exact file name matches will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Much easier using the **pathspec** option and **git_diff_index_to_workdit** instead of **git_diff_foreach**

```
char *pathspec = "foo.bar";
git_diff_options opts = GIT_DIFF_OPTIONS_INIT;
opts.pathspec.strings = &pathspec;
opts.pathspec.count = 1;
git_diff_index_to_workdir(&diff, repo, NULL, &opts);
```